# Entering data in oracle 11g from semicolon separated text file using python

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

Hi I am trying to enter data that is stored in semicolon separated text file using cx_Oracle(Python).

```
conn = co.connect('system/ayush@127.0.0.1/xe')
cur = conn.cursor()
f = open("C:\\Users\\goyal\\district.txt","r")

for line in f:
    record_split = line.split(";")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Demographic('A1','A2','A3') VALUES 
        (record_split[0],record_split[1],record_split[2])") 
conn.commit()
```

However , it is giving me following error

```
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4cbe704bce0e> in <module>()
        4 for line in f:
        5     record_split = line.split(";")
  ----> 6     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Demographics('A1','A2','A3') 
              VALUES(record_split[0],record_split[1],record_split[2]")
        7 conn.commit()

DatabaseError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Why is this error coming and how to solve this?

**EDIT**

I find python tutorial of reading csv and found this method

```
lines = csv.reader(open("district.txt","r"),delimiter=';')
next(lines,None)
for line in lines:
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Demographics(A1,A2,A3) VALUES(:1,:2,:3)",line) 

conn.commit()
```

However this read everything as text (even integer and float value) . So to enter value in database I have to explicitly change value to int and float is there any better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO Demographic(A1, A2, A3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
     (record_split[0],record_split[1],record_split[2]))
```

There were two things I could see wrong with your code:

1. Column names `A1`, `A2` and `A3` should not be enclosed in single quotes (`'`),
2. You hadn't quite understood how to get the parameter values into the query: your string wasn't using any of the values in `record_split`.  Use parameters (the `%s` markers) in the string and provide a tuple of values for the parameters afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Luke Woodward in his answer, column names should not be enclosed in single quotes. However, bind variables should be used, not the %s marker as in the following:

```
data = record_split[:3]
cur.execute("insert into Demographic (A1, A2, A3) values (:1, :2, :3)",
    data)
```

This is to avoid having to deal with special characters (such as embedded quotes) and to avoid security issues such as SQL injection.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I have edited my question please read and help me.

Comment: Yes, everything read from a CSV file is a string. It is your responsibility to convert this to integers or dates as needed!